# SQL Server : create a view with Union with data from first query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, union

My SQL is quite rusty, so much that I have not created a view before and I am not entirely sure how to do what I need. Perhaps I need a stored procedure. Here is the deal.

We have a a database of ticket history (purchases). We want to filter on a certain SKU, but we want all line items from each ticket that has that SKU. For isntance, Someone buys a shirt and a hat. I want to filter on the shirt to find everyone who wants a shirt but display the entire ticket showing the shirt and the hat.

I thought my query would be something like this but I don't think it would work.

```
select 
    ticket_id, post_date, qty_sold, total_price, sales_total
from 
    ticket_history 
where 
    sku = 'xxxx'

Union

select 
    sku as trans_sku, qty_sold as trans_qty_sold, desc as trans_desc, total_price as trans_total_price
from 
    ticket_history 
where 
    ticket_id = <the ticket id in first query>
```

Perhaps a sub-select is what is needed but I'm not too understanding of how to do that either.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I suppose you want a JOIN instead.

Comment: I figured out how to get this data via a Subquery in the "Where" statement. however, within a view I would want the filtering to be within the sub-query in case they want to filter on post date, etc. And, of course, they'll be filtering on SKU so that would need to be in the sub-query. So, I don't know is that is possible in a view. I know it is within a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a `UNION`, the selected columns must match between the two select's. (Same number of columns, and matching data types.)

Maybe you want a self join instead?

```
select th1.ticket_id, th1.post_date, th1.qty_sold, th1.total_price, th1.sales_total,
       th2.sku as trans_sku, th2.qty_sold as trans_qty_sold,
       th2.desc as trans_desc, th2.total_price as trans_total_price
from ticket_history th1
  left join ticket_history th2 on th2.ticket_id = th1.ticket_id
where th1.sku = 'xxxx'
```

`LEFT JOIN` to get th1 rows even if there are no matching th2 row.

Comment: I think with this one, I would not get all items from the full transaction. I would only get the lines where sku is 'xxxx'

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Either simply remove that WHERE completely, or move the th1.sku = 'xxxx' part to the ON clause (AND-ed.)

Comment: I accomplished the query this way with a subquery but I'm concerned that I need the filtering to be within the subquery. It looks like this:

select ticket_id, post_date, sku, qty_sold, desc, line_price, total_price from ticket_history where ticket_id in (select ticket_id from ticket_history where sku = 'xxx')

But the filtering has to be done in the sub-query or I won't get all the data I need.

Comment: Actually I just plugged in what you suggested and I think it's going to work. I believe I have all the data.

Comment: Okay, I'm running into a problem. I accomplished the query that I wanted by changing the where clause from th1.sku to th2.sku and that gave me everything I want. However, now that I created a view from it. I can't get it to filter on th2. It filters on th1 and only gives me the first sku and not the whole transaction..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here and whether `UNION` is what you are looking for or not.

In your query the columns are different and doesn't matched between the two queries. Any way, you can use a [**Common table Expression**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) so that you can reuse the subquery, this should solve your problem:

```
WITH FirstQuery
AS
(
   select
     ticket_id,
     post_date, 
     qty_sold,
     total_price, 
     sales_total
   from ticket_history 
  where sku = 'xxxx'
)
SELECT * 
FROM FirstQuery
UNION
SELECT 
  ... -- You should select the same number of columns
  ... -- and with the same data types to match the first columns
from ticket_history 
where ticket_id IN(SELECT ticket_id FROM FirstQuery);
```

Here the FirstQuery acts like a subquery, but here you can reuse it later like what we did and use it in the where clause.

But, again the columns you selected in the first query:

```
ticket_id,
 post_date, 
 qty_sold,
 total_price, 
 sales_total
```

are different than the columns you selected in the second query:

```
sku as trans_sku, 
qty_sold as trans_qty_sold, 
desc as trans_desc, 
total_price as trans_total_price
```

These columns should be matched (the count of them and data types). Otherwise you will got an error.

---

Things to note about [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

- the columns count should be the same between the two queries.
- The columns' names are driven from the first query.

Comment: If I do this within a view. Can the SKU be inserted into the first query, or will it go at the end and thus only give me the sku and not the whole transaction?

Comment: @Tomnibus - This depends on what you are trying to do and filter, if you need to filter and get the data for this specific SKU, then put it in the first query and add it too on the end of the last where clause: `where ticket_id IN(SELECT ticket_id FROM FirstQuery) and SKU = 'xxx';` Also note that if you need to pass different `SKU` value each time you need to call the view, you better create it as a procedure and make the sku as parameter and then call it with a specific value that you want to search for, this is better than a view.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to go with my subquery method I mention in the other answer thread and then create a stored procedure to accept input. Now I have to figure out how to manage the different types of input. They would want date range, single date, as well as one or more sku's. I have to write the SP to handle all the different types of input.